# i want to write a program in C that will give PI using Wallis Formula

Tags: c, pi

i want to write a program in C that will give PI using Wallis Formula

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
 long int i;
 double sum=1, term, pi = 0;
 /* Applying Formula */
 for(i=1;i< 1000000;i++)
 {
  term = pow((2*i),2)/((2*i-1)*(2*i+1));
  sum = sum * term;
 }
 pi = 2 * sum;
 printf("PI = %.10lf",pi);
 return 0;
}
```

i wrote that code and it keeps giving me PI = -inf

Comment: Tip: avoid `%f` for floating point number research.  use `%.17g`.

Comment: Using `sum = sum * term;` is a misuse of the name `sum`.  You're calculating a product, not a sum.  Or is there a typo in the expression and `*` should be `+`?  Hmmm…Wikipedia on [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) indicates that it is indeed a product (over an infinite number of terms).  So your nomenclature is dubious.  However, at one level, it is also harmless — just confusing.  Have you printed the values of `term` and `sum` as the calculation progresses?  Or at least some of the values?  You could stop when the new term is indistinguishable from `1.0`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: How does 1020² overflow anything?  I agree that the divisor expressions need to be coerced to `double` before the multiplication takes place (e.g. `double x = 2.0 * i; term = pow(x, 2) / ((x - 1.0) * (x + 1.0));` or something similar.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oops read code incorrectly as `pow(2, (2*i))`.  Comment removed.

Comment: Hi, If you are just looking to make the code run . replace long int to float 
It will give you the following result PI = 3.1408795764  - its not correct as far as I am concerned. but Its also not your question to make it correct. you wanted it to run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be, that your integer variable `i` is a 4-Byte value. When
the denominator `((2*i-1)*(2*i+1))` is evaluated, you get an overflow if `i` is greater than about 23170 `(Sqrt(2^31) / 2)`.
With the loop boundary set to 23170 your formula works. It also works when using an 8-Byte integer for `i` together with your original loop boundary.